# jQuery $(selector)[Property](Value)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask about jQuery syntax. I have found this syntax on bootstrap.js that there are:

```
$('.class')['height'](0)
```

And I could understand this, that this is equal with:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].style.height=0
```

But, I have found again the same syntax with:

```
$('.class')['height']($('.class')[0]['scrollHeight'])
```

and

```
$('.class')['height']($('.class')['height']())(0).offsetHeight
```

What this is? I could not understand this.

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand? This is simply setting the height of all `.class` elements to the `scrollHeight` of the first `.class` element.

Comment: I could not understand what this mean sir.. what the mean of $('.class')['height']($('.class')[0]['scrollHeight']) and $('.class')['height']($('.class')['height']())[0].offsetHeight .thanks :)

Comment: But *what exactly* is confusing you? Do you not know what the `.height` function does? Or what `scrollHeight` represents? Or are you simply confused by the use of bracket notation? Do you understand what the code means if I write `$('.class').height($('.class')[0].scrollHeight)`? We can only help you if we understand what your problem is. And for us to understand it, you have to describe/explain it.

Comment: `someobject['height']` is equivalent to `someobject.height` - does that help? (This is standard JavaScript syntax, nothing special for jQuery.)

Comment: aha.. thank you very much sir.. I just know that $(selector)[function](parameter) = $(selector).function(parameter) hehe. so now, I know that $('.class')['height'] = $('.class').height hehe. thanks sir... :)

Comment: yeah sir @nnnnnn :) i just know and understand now that someobject['somefunction'] = someobject.somefunction hehe.. thank you very much :)